# How are char* deallocated in C

Tags: c, string, memory

So I was reading through some code for a class and I am a little confused about how variable's are deallocated in C.

The code given is

```
#include<stdio.h>
main () {
    int n=0; 
    char *p = "hello world";
    while (*p!= 0)  {   // *p != '\0';
        putc(*p, stdout);
        p++;
    }
    printf("\np = %d", *p);
    printf("\np = %d\n", p);
}
```

So i get that you don't need to free any memory for the char* since no mallocs are happening but i don't get why this code wouldn't leak any memory... If you are incrementing a pointer for a string and thus moving pointer to the next block of memory (1byte) then aren't you losing the initial reference and all reference points that you increment over? How would would this memory be reclaimed without a reference point, unless one is saved by the compiler before this type of operation occurs. I would appreciate some insight on how this is being reclaimed!

Comment: Variables are deallocated when they pass out of scope.  Heap is deallocated when someone deallocates it.  Literal values (that are static strings in the compiled code) exist for the life of the program.  The space you're worried about is a literal string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The task of deallocating memory is imposed on the *owner* of that memory. Just because you have a pointer to some memory region does not mean that you *own* that memory and, therefore, does not mean that you are responsible for deallocating it.

String literal `"hello world"` is an object with static storage duration. It is stored in static memory. Static memory is always owned by the runtime environment. The runtime environment is aware of data stored in static memory. The runtime environment knows when that data has to be deallocated (which is easy, since static memory is basically "never" deallocated - it exists as long as your program runs).

So, again, you with your pointer `p` do not really own any memory in static region. You just happen to *refer* to that memory with your `p` . It is not your business to worry about deallocation of that memory. It will be properly deallocated when the time comes (i.e. when the program ends) and it will be done properly without any help from you and your pointer `p`. You can change your `p` as much as you want, you can make it point to a completely different memory location, or you can discard it without any reservations. Speaking informally, nobody cares about your `p`.

The only memory you can possibly *own* in a C program is memory you personally allocated with `malloc` (or other dynamic memory allocation functions). So, you have to remember to eventually call `free` for the memory that you allocated yourself (and you have to make sure you know the original value returned by `malloc` to pass to that `free`). All other kinds of memory (like *static* or *automatic*) are never owned by you, meaning that freeing it is not your business and preserving the original pointer values is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 12):

You aren't leaking any memory because you are not dynamically allocating any memory.  Memory leaks come from not freeing dynamically allocated memory.  Locally allocated memory (like `char *p`) or statically allocated memory (like the string `"hello world"` that `p` initially points at) cannot contribute to leaks.

Comment: And that's because they go out of scope at a future '}', right?

Comment: For block-scoped variables, yes, they go out of scope at a future `}`; for file-scoped or global-scoped variables, they are released by the O/S when the program exits.  (Or should I say 'file-scoped variables with internal or external linkage'?  Maybe that would be more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

You are not dynamically allocating any new memory, hence you do not need to free it.

Answer (score 2):

The string literal `"hello world"` is an object which is part of the program itself. When the `"hello world"` expression is evaluated, the program essentially obtains a pointer to a piece of itself. That memory cannot be deallocated while the program is running; that would be equivalent to making a "hole" in the program. The memory has the same lifetime as the program itself.

In the C language, the programmer is not required to manage memory which has the same lifetime as the program: this is externally managed (or mismanaged, as the case may be) by the environment which starts the program, and deals with the aftermath when the program terminates.

Of course, the memory still has to be managed; it's just that the responsibility does not lie with the C program. (At least, not in an environment which provides a hosted implementation of the C language. The rules for some embedded system might be otherwise!)

In a program that is embedded, the string literal (along with the rest of the program) could actually live in ROM. So there might really be nothing to clean up. The pointer is an address which refers to some permanent location on a chip (or several chips).

Answer (score 0):

In short: because the program itself is short. You could be doing any `malloc` you want in there, and no leaks would actually happen, since all the memory is handed back to the OS as soon as the process ends. A leak would not be an issue in your example. Anyway,

in your case, a leak is not happening, because the variable `p` is pointing to a literal string, which is located in the data segment of the memory (i.e. it is a constant, written in the executable). This kind of memory cannot be de-allocated, because its space is fixed.
Actually, it is false that this is not a problem, because a very big executable, with lots of big constants in it, could have a remarkable memory footprint, but anyway **this is not called a leak, because memory usage may be big, but it does not increase over time, which is the main point of a memory leak** (hence the name *leak*).

Comment: I find it really unpolite to downvote without explaining why.

Comment: In modern general purpose operating systems, all memory leaks are cleaned up when the program terminates. A memory leak is a result of the program dynamically allocating memory and not freeing that memory before it terminates. (The rules used to be different on some older operating systems, like the original AmigaOS, and I think that older versions of Mac OS — version 9 and more likely before that — was somewhat vulnerable too. The rules could be different in an embedded O/S, even a modern, current version.) Your answer implies that `int main(void){void*vp=malloc(10);}` does not leak; it does!

Comment: Yeah, ok... I was speaking of that specific case, assuming Win/Linux/OSX. If you make a malloc, you should free it, also in moder OSes, because you or someone else could decide one day to embed your program and run your main in a loop, turning a non-leak to a leak.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your variables locally, the compiler knows how much space is required for each variable and when you run your program, each local variable (and also each function call) is put on stack. Just after return statement (or } bracket if void function) each local variable is popped from stack, so you don't have to free it.

When you call new operator (or malloc in pure C), the compiler doesn't know the size of the data, so the memory is allocated runtime on heap.

Why I'm explaining this is fact that whenever you call new or malloc (or calloc), it's your responsibility to free memory you don't want to use anymore.

Comment: Deallocation of locals would explain why you don't need to deallocate the pointer itself, but it doesn't really explain why you don't have to allocate the memory pointed at by the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, incrementing a pointer in C doesn't create or lose "references", nor does it cause any copying or other altering of the memory that the pointer points to.  The pointer in this case is just a number that happens to point to a statically allocated area of memory.

Incrementing the pointer doesn't alter the bytes that the pointer used to point to.  The "H", is still there.  But the program now thinks that the string starts with "e".  (It knows where the end of the string is because by convention strings in C end with a `null`.

There are no checks that the pointer points to what you think it should, or any valid area at all. The program itself could lose track of an area of memory (for instance if you set `p=0`), or increment p beyond the end of the string, but the compiler doesn't keep track of this (or prevent it), and it doesn't de-allocate the memory used for the string.

If you change the pointer to point to the "wrong" location in memory, fun (bad) things will happen - such as page faults, stack overflows and core dumps.

Comment: If you are dynamically allocating memory and you increment a pointer without saving a reference to the initial node then you are most certainly losing your reference. If you were implementing a linked list, and just decided to advance your header a few slots without freeing your node first then I don't see how this wouldn't constitute as losing a reference to a memory block because you would have no way of deallocating it and you would have subsequent leaks...in this context we are using statically allocated memory thats popped from the stack when its lifetime expires but not the general case.

Comment: Yes, if you traverse a linked list (and your list doesn't have backwards/parent pointers), and you keep adding to that list, you could leak (be unable to free) memory.  You can "lose" any memory "reference" by altering pointers.  But a leak implies a growing (dynamic) pool of memory, (usually) obtained from malloc().